# First ever transfer in football

Tags: football, history, transaction, transfer

What was the first ever recorded in transfer in football, by transfer I mean the first time a club bought another player's contract from a club?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first ever [transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progression_of_British_football_transfer_fee_record) was Willie Groves to Aston Villa in 1893 for £100. This was after player registration was introduced in 1885 by the FA making it possible for a player to play for a club only after he had been registered with them.

Just out of interest that sum of £100 would now be worth £10881.81 taking [inflation](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/education/Pages/inflation/calculator/flash/default.aspx) into account.